# building rpm package goes into a loop on redhat linux

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt, rpmbuild

Attempting to build a package from within Eclipse CDT environment.  The apps is C based. We have a spec file describing all the elements contained in the package.  There is a Makefile in the src directory that builds all the executables.

We now want to bundle the package into an installable rpm from the eclipse IDE when a build is performed.

We did this by adding a new tag to the all: tag.  In this tag we add the commands to perform the build of the package.

When this script fires after the commands in the all: tag are run, it runs the package build in a loop over and over.  Is there something missing here that controls this behaviour?

Comment: I've gotten infinite loops trying to `make` if my system time is bad ... worth a quick look

Comment: A typical RPM Spec file contains instructions for building the software, often by running `make`.  If running `make` causes `rpmbuild` to try to build from the same or an equivalent SPEC file then an unbounded recursion is created.

Comment: I can run the build_pkg.sh script outside at the shell with no problem.  It uses tar to create the appl.tar.gz and then runs rpmbuild -ta appl.tar.gz against it.  When used in the all: tag in the Makefile it runs over and over again.  Strange behaviour.

Comment: here is the command in the appl: tag section that does the packaging:
appl:
<TAB>@echo "building package..."
<TAB>-cd ../.. && /usr/local/bin/build_pkg.sh -b -a $(APP_NAME)
<TAB>@echo "Package build complete"

The build_pkg.sh script exits with either a 0 or a 1 value depending on whether any problems were encountered during packaging.

The build happens in the application src directory so appl/src.  That is why I have to cd ../.. before invoking the script.

Comment: @JohnBollinger what about in the specfile, just having it do the make against the packaging directive tag only...ie: no make clean, make all?? that work?

Comment: @user3053087, if you have information to add to the question then please *add it to the question*.  Overall, I think it unlikely that we'll be able to troubleshoot this for you without considerable detail about what is actually in your Makefile and spec file.  With some work, you ought to be able to cut out the unnecessary bits -- likely most of both files -- to arrive at a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.  That's our usual standard for questions seeking debugging help.

Comment: I resolved it.  Here's how.  I had dependencies in the Makefile on the package which should have been dependent on the TARGETS and EXTRA_TARGETS before allowing the rpm to be built.  Problem 1.
The other issue was I as attempting to build the tar archive in the workspace directory of eclipse - which exists as a sub-dir off the users home directory.  This proved problematic as well.  The build_pkg.sh scrip t was modified to create the tar archive in the ~.  rpmbuild then works as it should.

Comment: One additonal note...the script being invoked - build_pkg.sh - uses the variable MAKELEVEL to determine if it is being run in recursive manner and exits with a 0 if it is greater than 1.  This ensures that the package build ONLY runs once.